# Выборка из разных серверов MYSQL за 1 запрос

Tags: linked-list

Если у меня есть 2 разных физически сервера MySQL, могу ли я с сервера А,БД С сделать селект на сервер В,БД Е
?
Есть ли какой-то аналог Linked - server?